# excel CountIf or

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Both options work fine as you can see in my picture of my spreadsheet in column R & Q where the counts are.
Most of my columns are in military time formats like 24:00 one of the column I am working on is the X column that I am trying to get added to this time count if possible I a Number column where the numbers start from 10,11,13 and so on. Long story short.
I need Numbers in column X # 10 ,11 to be in the count for count for column O as you can see in column Q & R  I got it set up for my count and it works just fine but that’s without the special deal I need from column X where I only needs these numbers from 10,11, a few from # 13.
So, in a nut shell I just need it to say give me the column O times if there is a # 10,11,13 in column X 
= COUNTIF($O$13:$O$1000,">=0:21")-COUNTIF($O$13:$O$1000,">0:30")

Connection time

*Connection time*
[image: Connection Time]

Comment: I am not sure why in the entry it specifies the O column while in the text it specifies the X column..

Comment: Even after editing your post, it is very hard to read because you don't use any punctuation. I can't really tell what you are asking because it's impossible to tell where one phrase ends and the next one starts. Punctuation is made for that, so please use it. Also, please add a screenshot of your data layout and manually put in the expected result. Then explain in simple words (using punctuation) what logic leads to the result. Edit your question to do that.

Comment: @RyanL He says "row X", not column X. It's a concept, not a cell address.

Comment: @teylyn, thx for correction. My overlook. Then I still don't have clear clue of the entire picture.

Comment: I think I got it. In column O you have some times. In column X you have some codes. And what you want to get is to count times from column O that are between 21 and 31 AND have 10,11 or 13 in column X. Is that right?

Comment: yes I only need the 21 and 31 minutes, counts from those 3 code # 10,11,13, so i just need a way to tell it to pretty much ignore all other cone # in that column.if you click on the highlighted " Connection time" just under my formula,  that should show you a snapshot of my spreadsheet , you might get an idea of what i am talking  about. thanks again.

Comment: You should cut all the superfluous stuff out your question - if you want to give a commentary do it in the comments... Punctuation/grammar.. "In Column X I got A column called Code" =>. Column X is named Code.. Only mention it if it has a bearing. Also you could use Google Docs and link a version.... Has similar functionality. You can probably even import your spreadsheet... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480 - similar functionality. You have 0:21 - 0:30.. What's that all about? Zeros? O21 or 0.21? etc. If it's meant to be time, you want to strip out that stuff, and add things up probably using decimals so 30 seconds is 0.5 min.. Or convert everything to seconds... Then you can convert back after.If it's minutes and you want the granularity split it into columns. LEFT(cell,FIND(":"),cell) , RIGHT(cell,len(cell)-find(":")). May be off by one either way so a +1,-1 may be needed... Then convert text to number VALUE(text). And countif does not allow strings for comparison. So quotes around last parameter are a "no no"! Only numbers..

Comment: thanks, as you can see on the picture of my spreadsheet that my entry works just fine for the connection part in column O , That`s the numbers showing up in column Q & R , I had just hoped that there was a way i could find a way to add to it where it would only would give me the times in column O , if the number in column X was only one off the 3 numbers I Need 10,11,13 but none of the other numbers i get in that row needs to be in count. hope this help a bit. I was trying to attach a spreadsheet but system said not enough points or something like that.

Comment: If the data type of your data cells are a string then you'd have to do the left/right extract substring formulas.  If they were numeric and formatted to appear like timestamps then your countif should probably be converting to a decimal notation with minutes or seconds as a decimal fraction depending on whether you are working in hours, minutes, seconds etc. This link may also help https://excelribbon.tips.net/T012398_Counting_Times_within_a_Range.html There's even videos on Youtube that might help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ulXRBA3ikI

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
=COUNTIF($O$13:$O$1000,">=0:21")-COUNTIF($O$13:$O$1000,">0:30")
```

Try the following:

```
=COUNTIF($O$13:$O$1000,">="&Time(0,21,0))-COUNTIF($O$13:$O$1000,">"&time(0,30,0))
```